# Entity Framework with dynamic value set in where clause not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

My database and corresponding class structure is as par below

```
Class Helper:
   List<Util> UtilityInfo,
   
Class Util :
   int Id
```

I have filter array with below values

```
int[] idArray = { 1, 2, 3};
```

Expected query format:

```
 _dbContent.Helper.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && ut.Util.id = 1 || ut => ut.Util.id == 2 || ut => ut.Util.id == 3));
```

I want to achieve same through looping on the id's array.

When I am execute above query it's work fine but want to construct same dynamically using loop.

I have tried with below pattern but it added some class level expression at `[ut.Util.id == item]`, observed the same inside Debug expression content in Visual Studio.

Finally because of which getting error at the time of retrieving data.

```
var helperInfo = new List<Helper>()

foreach(var item in idArray)
{
    helperInfo = helperInfo.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && ut.Util.id == item));
}
```

**Note**: I have successfully done above with below pattern but want to achieve same through looping

```
helper= helper.Where
(
  hp => idArray.Any
  (
     uId => hp.utilityInfo!= null &&
     v.utilityInfo.Any
     (
        ut => ut.User != null &&
        ut.Id == uId
     )
  )).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

You can iterate over `IQueryable` by same concept in prev update like below or use expression

```
var helperInfo = _dbContent.Helper;
var filteredHelperInfo = new List<Helper>();

foreach(var item in idArray)
{
   filteredHelperInfo.AddRange(helperInfo.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && ut.Util.id == item)).ToList());
}
```

If I now understand well if you need to query on the helper list using loop you need to create new list and add filtered items in it in each iteration like below

**Note**: in your code in first iteration your list will filtered with first id second time you'll not found any items in list with second id so your list will be empty

```
var helperInfo = new List<Helper>();
var filteredHelperInfo = new List<Helper>();

foreach(var item in idArray)
{
   filteredHelperInfo.AddRange(helperInfo.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && ut.Util.id == item)));
}
```

**Update**

If I now understand well if you need to query on the helper list using loop you need to create new list and add filtered items in it in each iteration like below

**Note**: in your code in first iteration your list will filtered with first id second time you'll not found any items in list with second id so your list will be empty

```
var helperInfo = new List<Helper>();
var filteredHelperInfo = new List<Helper>();

foreach(var item in idArray)
{
   filteredHelperInfo.AddRange(helperInfo.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && ut.Util.id == item)));
}
```

**Old answer for minimal code**

You can use contains instead of looping like below, this will get all items with the same ids in array you mentioned

```
helperInfo = helperInfo.Where(hp => hp.utilityInfo.Any(ut => ut != null && idArray.Contains( ut.Util.id)));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..! using .ToList() I am able to get expected result. But I want to fire query on IQueryable<Helper> object.so I want to prepare query as par "ExpectedFormat"

Comment: sorry ,can't understand!! please clarify what you need exactly to be able to help

Comment: As I am performing various where clauses on main object and at the end I am retrieving data from database. If I execute the same query and returning ToList() object which will return the expected data. But if I have append any other where clauses and check the debug expression of my query it shows some class level annotation in query which is not get resolved at the time of final execution and throw the error. So I want to construct the simple query which I have posted in my original post

Answer (score 0):

You just can use this

```
int[] idarray = { 1, 3, 5 };
var list = context.Helpers.Include(x => x.Utilities.Where(y => idarray.Contains(y.Id))).ToList();
```

### Result

[image]